# Storing media files in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I tried to store the audio/video files in the database.

Is cassandra able to do that ? if yes, how do we store the media files in cassandra.

How about storing the metadata and original audio files in cassandra

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html

Answer (score 13):

Yes, Cassandra is definitely able to store files in its database, as "blobs", strings of bytes.

However, it is **not** ideal for this use case:

First, you are limited in blob size. The hard limit is 2GB size, so large videos are out of the question. But worse, the documentation from Datastax (the commercial company behind Cassandra's development) suggests that even 1 MB (!) is too large - see https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html.

One of the reasons why huge blobs are a problem is that Cassandra offers no API for fetching parts of them - you need to read (and write) a blob in one CQL operation, which opens up all sorts of problems. So if you want to store large files in Cassandra, you'll probably want to split them up into many small blobs - not one large blob.

The next problem is that some of Cassandra's implementation is inefficient when the database contains files (even if split up to a bunch of smaller blobs). One of the problems is the compaction algorithm, which ends up copying all the data over and over (a logarithmic number of times) on disk; An implementation optimized for storing files would keep the file data and the metadata separately, and only "compact" the metadata. Unfortunately neither Cassandra nor Scylla implement such a file format yet.

All-in-all, you're probably better off storing your metadata in Cassandra but the actual file content in a different object-store implementation.

Comment: You can still store large files in Cassandra but you have to break it up into smaller pieces.

Comment: Note that as I noted, breaking up the file into small pieces will solve some of the problems, but it won't solve the "write amplification" problem: If you split the file into a thousand pieces, all these thousand pieces will get copied again and again during compaction. The write amplification issue may be acceptable for your use case, in which case, by all means you can use Cassandra or Scylla for storing large files (split to pieces). But it is less efficient than a database that doesn't do all those unnecessary copies and just compacts small metadata.